# Change corner radius using SKAction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, transition, skaction

I would like to change corner radius size of a SKSpriteNode using the SKAction.

```
// creating a rectangle with cornerRadius:20
SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];
shape.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 100, 100) cornerRadius:20].CGPath;
shape.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
shape.strokeColor = [SKColor blackColor];
shape.blendMode = SKBlendModeAdd;
[self addChild:shape];

// transition that transforms to `shape` with cornerRadius:5
SKAction *action = [SKAction ????, cornerRadius:5];
[shape runAction:action];
```

The transition should look like this:
[image]

Comment: There is no transition/action that transforms a shape. You'd have to change the shape node's path over time, somehow interpolating between the two shapes, probably by slowly reducing the corner radius over time.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks for the hint. Can you point me somewhere where I could learn more about your approach? Thx!

Comment: Not really, I mean a simple test would be to change a shape node's path in the scene's update by assigning a new path the way you did in your code sample and see what the results are before you try to make it work in the way you need it to.